# How to pass to a new slide on Beamer?

Tags: beamer, slideshow

On beamer document class
I would like to know how to start writing on a new slide?

There is a bunch of text that the current slide had not  enough space, so the text is not complete.

I know that for a document class Article one could use \newpage but it's not working on Beamer

Why?

Help me please

Comment: You have `frame` environment. Just put the "outside" text to the next `frame`.

Comment: The `[allowframebreaks]` option might also be interesting.

Comment: @leandriis how to use that inside a \begin{enumerate} ?

Comment: `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{enumerate}
<your items>
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}`  Apart from that, it is (almost) always a good idea to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate your question and show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `allowframebreaks` option automatically splits the contents of a `frame` over several frames if the contents don't fit into a single frame. This also works if the frame contains an `enumerate` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{enumerate}
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\item item
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for removing this from the list of unanswered questions!